# Servlet mapping to default / in tomcat

Tags: tomcat, servlets, application-server, tomcat7

I am using an external program that knows to send requests only to localhost:8080/

Is it safe to define the my servlet like this:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Since also tomcat default servlet is mapped to it. I am using tomcat 7.

What is the priority of the servlets? If I have mapping to /resources/* and *.jsf and the URL is like this localhost:8080/resources/test.jsf - what will be invoked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, you would want to override the default servlet?
You could add a context element within the default `<Host>` element in tomcat's conf/server.xml

For example:

```
<Context path="" docBase="app" />
```

where app is a folder in the webapps directory.
See the documentation [here](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/context.html) for more information.

> > It is NOT recommended to place  elements directly in the server.xml file. This is because it makes modifying the Context configuration more invasive since the main conf/server.xml file cannot be reloaded without restarting Tomcat.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi!No I didn't mean it. I meant to ask if it's safe to do so

Comment: Ah, right.
  
You might want to look at the [servlet spec](http://www.scribd.com/doc/23278127/107/SRV-11-2-Specification-of-Mappings):

_A string containing only the / character indicates the "default" servlet of the application. In this case the servlet path is the request URI minus the context path and the path info is null._

_The pattern / will make your servlet the default servlet for the app, meaning it will pick up every pattern that doesn't have another exact match._

So I would say it's safe. Take a note of the implicit mappings etc mentioned in the specs.